# Data not getting inside common functions in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I have created a common method for menu access check in a service module called 'AuthService'.It intract with services in class DataService.The common menu access function included in all components onInit .But data not getting inside the components.inside 'AuthService' i am getting correct data.

**AuthService class**

```
menuAccessCheck(currentRoute) {
    var dataObj = {
        menu_url : currentRoute
    };

    this.data.checkMenuAccess(dataObj)
      .subscribe(datas => {
        // console.log(datas.data.can_add);
                datas.data

        }
      );
  }
```

**DataService  Class**

```
  checkMenuAccess(postData){
        this.ctrURL         =   API_URL+"menu/access/check";
        this.ajaxdata       =   postData;
        var localStore      =   JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + localStore.token);

        return this.http
            .post(this.ctrURL,JSON.stringify(this.ajaxdata),{ headers: headers })
            .pipe(map(data => { return data.json(); }));
    }
```

**dashboard component**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.authCheck();
    var menuAccess = this.auth.menuAccessCheck(this.router.url);
    console.log("my value="+menuAccess);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code can help you to access the data.

```
menuAccessCheck(currentRoute) {
    var dataObj = {
        menu_url : currentRoute
    };

    return this.data.checkMenuAccess(dataObj);

  }



private menuAccess: any;

ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.authCheck();
    this.auth.menuAccessCheck(this.router.url).subscribe(datas => {
      this.menuAccess = datas;
    }); 
}
```